# Does liquibase recognize if table is already up to date before executing changeSet?

Tags: liquibase

In our case liquibase is used to update databses for existing installation. New installations are already up to date.

Assuming we have got a new installation. Starting the application will force to execute liquibase changesets (e.g. change type of a column) but as I mentioned before there is nothing to update as the column already was created with the correct type.

Does liquibase recognize that the table column is already up to date or does it try to execute the changeset as there is no entry within the databasechangelog table for it?

Answer (score 5):

Liquibase uses an alternative approach that avoids a need to analyze the target database's data dictionary. This makes DB operations simpler and more cross platform.

A special table "DATABASECHANGELOG" keeps a record of the changesets applied to the target database instance. This table also contains a checksum (calculated at runtime) to determine if changsets are altered between runs of liquibase.

So if you altered the type of a table column, liquibase can detect this and can throw an error, when run against an existing database. (Obviously, on a new DB, the table would be created as expected).

Finally, the [changeset documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html) describes two optional attributes ("runAlways" and "runOnChange") which could tell lqiuibase to reapply a changeset more than once to a database. There is also a ["clearCheckSums" command](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) that can be used to reset the checksums on an existing database. Obviously you need to know what you're doing when using such an option :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that Liquibase is holding its state within the DATABASECHANGELOG table. My question is another: Because we have a new installation the database is up to date but the changesets (defined for updating the software) aren't run and shouldn't be executed as they only try to update what's already there. But there is no entry for the execution within the DATABASECHANGELOG. Does Liquibase detect that the changeset will only change whats already there and do not execute the statements or will it regardless execute the statements? Thanks

Comment: @ms.oe Check the "changelogSync" liquibase command: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html

Comment: Hopefully this is clear, but you should only use the changelogSync command if you somehow know that the database is actually 'in sync' with the changelog. Liquibase does not do any checking of the actual database structure when running that command.

Comment: @SteveDonie That is correct. It effectively just marks the changeset as executed.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase will not recognize anything automatically.

But you can use <[preConditions](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html)/> in your changeSet to check if your changeSet must be applied or not.